# FFMPEG Detect volume of streaming (PHP)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, volume, detect

I spent last 4 days trying to acheive that but with no luck,

I am trying to detect volume of streaming link or save audio file, using the FFmpeg I tried every single command line.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i amovie=sample1.aac,volumedetect -f null -y test.txt
```

Output

```
There was a problem! Array (
    [0] => FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
    [1] => built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
    [2] => configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
    [3] => libavutil 50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
    [4] => libavcodec 52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
    [5] => libavformat 52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
    [6] => libavdevice 52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
    [7] => libavfilter 1.19. 0 / 1.19. 0
    [8] => libswscale 0.11. 0 / 0.11. 0
    [9] => libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
    [10] => Unknown input format: 'lavf'
)
```

Basically my problem now is :

```
 Unknown input format: 'lavf'
```

Any help please

My FFMpeg Version is

```
[root@bea ~]# ffmpeg -formats | grep lavfi
```

FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0

From PHP info

```
ffmpeg
```

ffmpeg-php version  0.6.0-svn
ffmpeg-php built on Sep 21 2013 15:38:20
ffmpeg-php gd support   enabled
ffmpeg libavcodec version   Lavc52.72.2
ffmpeg libavformat version  Lavf52.64.2
ffmpeg swscaler version SwS0.11.0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
ffmpeg.allow_persistent 0   0
ffmpeg.show_warnings    0   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your ffmpeg is too old to support lavfi. Find out by doing ffmpeg -formats. lavfi should be part of the list? You can try

```
ffmpeg -formats | grep lavfi
```

The following works fine otherwise.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i amovie=sample1.aac,volumedetect 
[aac @ 0x1e26a20] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[lavfi @ 0x1e25a60] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, lavfi, from 'amovie=sample1.aac,volumedetect':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
n_samples: 2048
[Parsed_volumedetect_1 @ 0x1e27280] mean_volume: -61.9 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_1 @ 0x1e27280] max_volume: -49.0 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_1 @ 0x1e27280] histogram_49db: 14
```

Comment: I have updated my post with the ffmpeg version thanks my friend

Comment: @MohamedMostafa, there is not lavfi filter in your ffmpeg. You need a newer version.

Comment: Am sorry if it looks like a silly question I am new at this FFmpeg thing, but I have just installed it? can you tell me how did you know? and how it should look like when i have lavfi? and how to update? thanks a lot

Comment: @MohamedMostafa, your version is 0.6.0. Go to ffmpeg.org. The latest version is 2.0. If you do ffmpeg -formats, do you see the list? lavfi should be one of them if it is supported. You need to install a newer version of ffmpeg. If I remember right lavfi was added much later after 0.6.0.

Comment: I think I found the problem but I cannot solve it , the version of the FFMpeg was 0.6.0 but I updated it to the FFMpeg 2, but since I am using it with PHP the problem still present since the FFMpeg-php extension the latest updated version is 0.6.0 http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/ffmpeg-php/

Comment: This [code]ffmpeg -f lavfi -i amovie=sample1.aac,volumedetect [/code] is working in the linux terminal but doesn't work in [code]exec ('ffmpeg -f lavfi -i amovie=sample1.aac,volumedetect ');[/code] is it possible to use FFmpeg without the FFmpeg-php extension which seems to be out of date

Answer (score -1):

I solved it Thanks to AV501,

I did updated the FFMpeg to FFmpeg 2

and I used the code as following :

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f lavfi -i amovie=sample1.aac,volumedetect
```

And it did work fine,